# How to find item on table X that not in table Y

Tags: sql, join

I have a table ORDRE:

```
NoOrdre(int)   CodeClient (varchar 50)
1               85
2               85
3               85
4               85
5               85
6               85
```

And table LV:

```
CodeClient(varchar 50)     NoOrdrCumm (varchar 100)
85                         1
85                         2_3_4
```

I want to create a SQL script that shows the result 5 and 6. That mean find no order on table order that not exist in table LV

I have create some script, but it does not work:

```
SELECT ORDRE.NO_ORDRE
      ,ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT   
  FROM [ORDRE]
  INNER JOIN LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL ON ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.CODE_CLIENT
                             -- and ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR = LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.DATE_CLOTURE
  WHERE STATUT_ORDRE = 2  
  AND    ORDRE.NO_ORDRE not like '%'+ LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL + '%'  


  Select CONVERT(varchar(10), ORDRE.NO_ORDRE)  from ORDRE where not CONVERT(varchar(10), ORDRE.NO_ORDRE) in (select LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL from LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL)
  and   STATUT_ORDRE = 2
```

Any idea ?

These scripts:

```
    Select CONVERT(varchar(10), ORDRE.NO_ORDRE)  from ORDRE where not CONVERT(varchar(10), ORDRE.NO_ORDRE) in (select LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL from LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL)
     and   STATUT_ORDRE = 2   

    Select  ORDRE.NO_ORDRE from ORDRE where not EXISTS (select * from LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL where LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL.NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL = CONVERT(varchar(10), ORDRE.NO_ORDRE))

 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), ORDRE.NO_ORDRE), CODE_CLIENT FROM ORDRE
EXCEPT
SELECT NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL, CODE_CLIENT FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL
```

The above script returns: `2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

How can i create temporary table to atomize the NoOrdrCumm and then start the searching

Comment: The best thing to do (if possible) is to actually **stop using a varchar column to store multiple values**. You're using a relational database, so use it the way it's designed to be used: create a table that lists relation between the row and the multiple values and use that to capture the `1:n` relation.

Comment: I completely agree with Jiri Tousek. If, however, you must stick to this terrible database design for whatever reason, then tag your DBMS. You might need string manipulation, which is DBMS dependant.

Comment: A related note: you might want to look into atomizing your LV table :)

Answer (score 1):

try this (t-sql):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ORDRE (NoOrdre INT, CodeClient VARCHAR(50))

INSERT dbo.ORDRE
SELECT 1, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 85

CREATE TABLE dbo.LV (CodeClient VARCHAR(50), NoOrdrCumm VARCHAR(100))

INSERT dbo.LV
SELECT 85, '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 85, '2_3_4'

--SELECT *
--FROM dbo.ORDRE o

--SELECT *
--FROM dbo.LV o

SELECT o.*
FROM dbo.ORDRE o
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LV l ON CHARINDEX(CAST(o.NoOrdre AS VARCHAR(100)), l.NoOrdrCumm) > 0
WHERE l.CodeClient IS NULL
```

to fix Jiri Tousek's concern:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ORDRE (NoOrdre INT, CodeClient VARCHAR(50))

INSERT dbo.ORDRE
SELECT 1, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 85 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 85

CREATE TABLE dbo.LV (CodeClient VARCHAR(50), NoOrdrCumm VARCHAR(100))

INSERT dbo.LV
SELECT 85, '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 85, '2_3_4'
-- UNION ALL SELECT 85, '5_3_1_42_6' --uncomment this to test numbers with more than 1 digit

--SELECT *
--FROM dbo.ORDRE o

--SELECT *
--FROM dbo.LV o

SELECT o.*
FROM dbo.ORDRE o
    --LEFT JOIN dbo.LV l ON CHARINDEX(CAST(o.NoOrdre AS VARCHAR(100)), l.NoOrdrCumm) > 0
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LV l ON CHARINDEX(CONCAT('_', o.NoOrdre, '_'), CONCAT('_', l.NoOrdrCumm, '_')) > 0
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LV l2 ON CHARINDEX(CONCAT(o.NoOrdre, '_'), CONCAT('_', l.NoOrdrCumm, '_')) > 0
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LV l3 ON CHARINDEX(CONCAT('_', o.NoOrdre), CONCAT('_', l.NoOrdrCumm, '_')) > 0
WHERE l.CodeClient IS NULL
    AND l2.CodeClient IS NULL
    AND l3.CodeClient IS NULL
```

Comment: This will match both `2` and `4` when the `NoOrdrCumm` contains `42` ... which is exactly why it's a bad idea to store multiple values in the varchar. You'd have to actually check that there's `_` on both sides of the matched number, plus account for when it's the first, last or only number present.

Comment: Nice trick using `_` around the actual column's contents, that makes it a lot easier. I think you now only need to check for `CONCAT('_', o.NoOrdre, '_')`. The other two variants might actually harm you - won't your current code match `2_` against `_42_` (after adding the `_`s)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

use

```
table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id != t2.id
```

The `JOIN ON` is actually an expression, normally people want it to match so you see `t1.id=t2.id` everywhere.

For your case where you don't want it to match you can use the `!=` operator instead of the `=` operator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's what you need but you can try this:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM ORDRE o

EXCEPT

SELECT o.*
FROM ORDRE o
 LEFT JOIN LV l ON o.CodeClient = l.CodeClient
WHERE instr(l.NoOrdrCumm,o.NoOrder) > 0
;
```